# Find $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}{2n+1}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Few weeks ago, I've posted a question about finding sum of such series.

But actually , after this time I steel have a problem with calculating the sum.

First problem was : author of solution used $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{n}}{2n+1} = \operatorname{arctanh}(z)$. But actually I don't know how to find this Taylor-representation.

Second one is : actually I want to find it a bit easier, maybe longer, but easier. So I'll try to make my attempt to find mistakes:

*My attempt :*

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(nx)t^{2n+1}}{2n+1} = \Im \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{inx}t^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$, so we can differentiate it because out series is uniformly convergent(W-test), so :

$\displaystyle F'(t) = \Im\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(e^{ix}t^{2})^{n} = \Im\frac{1}{1-t^2e^{ix}} = \frac{t^{2}\sin(x)}{t^4-2t^2\cos(x)+1}$, now rewrite it so : $$\displaystyle \frac{A\sin(x)}{t^2-e^{ix}}+\frac{B\sin(x)}{t^{2}-e^{-ix}}$$, where $\displaystyle A = \frac{e^{ix}}{2i}$ and $\displaystyle B = \frac{-e^{-ix}}{2i}$, so $\displaystyle \frac{A\sin(x)}{t^{2}-e^{ix}} + \frac{B\sin(x)}{t^{2}-e^{-ix}} = \frac{1}{2i} \left( \frac{e^{ix}}{t^{2}-e^{ix}}-\frac{e^{-ix}}{t^{2}-e^{-ix}} \right) = \frac{1}{2i}\left(\frac{a}{t-e^{ix/2}} + \frac{b}{t+e^{ix/2}} + \frac{c}{t-e^{-ix/2}} + \frac{d}{t+e^{-ix/2}}\right) = \frac{1}{4i}\left( \frac{e^{-ix/2}}{t-e^{ix/2}} - \frac{e^{-ix/2}}{t+e^{ix/2}} - \frac{e^{ix/2}}{t-e^{-ix/2}} + \frac{e^{ix/2}}{t+e^{-ix/2}}\right)$.

Now we can integrate it : $$\displaystyle F(t) = \frac{1}{4i}e^{-ix/2} \log{\frac{t-e^{ix/2}}{t+e^{ix/2}}} + \frac{1}{4i}e^{ix/2}\log\frac{t+e^{-ix/2}}{t-e^{-ix/2}} + C = \frac{1}{4i}\sin(x/2)\log\frac{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{t\cos(x/2)}{t^{2}+1}}{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{t\cos(x/2)}{t^{2}+1}} + \frac{1}{4}\cos(x/2)\log\frac{t^{2}-2ti\sin(x/2)+1}{t^{2}+2ti\sin(x/2)+1} + C$$, now let $t = 1$.
$$\displaystyle \frac{1}{4}\sin(x/2)\log{\frac{1-2\cos(x/2)}{1+2\cos(x/2)}}+\frac{1}{4i}\cos(x/2)\log(-1)+C$$. That's the moment I've stucked, actually using $e^{i \pi} = -1$, I can evaluate the $\log(-1)$, but it's course of real-analysis. Maybe there is a better way to calculate it?

**The answer is :** $\frac{\pi}{4}\cos(x/2)-\frac{1}{2}\sin(x/2)\log(\cot(x/4))$

Any hint , will be appreciate!

Comment: Perhaps the Fourier sine series may work.

Comment: It is not hard to find the Taylor expansion of $\text{arctanh} x$.

Comment: @xpaul it will be cool, if you present some links.

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$ \text{arctanh}\,x=\frac12[\ln(1+x)-\ln(1-x)]. $$
Using
$$ \ln(1-x)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n},-1\le x<1 $$
one obtains, for $|x|<1$,
\begin{eqnarray}
\text{arctanh}\,x&=&\frac12[\ln(1+x)-\ln(1-x)]\\
&=&\frac12\bigg[\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-x)^{n+1}}{n}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n}\bigg]\\
&=&\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}.
\end{eqnarray}